# iOS swift and Parse: localDataStore

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to use parse (iOS sdk v1.6.0 ) with is with switch and following the documentation I made:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    Parse.setApplicationId("appKey", clientKey:"clientKey")
```

but Launching the app I have this error:

```
2014-12-11 20:29:41.627 ShareTales[62985:626799] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104873f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104163bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104873e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   ShareTales                          0x00000001027ce7ba +[Parse getApplicationId] + 53
4   ShareTales                          0x00000001027b3140 +[PFInternalUtils dataFilePath:] + 53
5   ShareTales                          0x00000001027515ff -[PFSQLiteDatabase initWithName:] + 200
6   ShareTales                          0x00000001027517b4 +[PFSQLiteDatabase databaseWithName:] + 69
7   ShareTales                          0x0000000102766e79 +[PFOfflineStore _initializeTables] + 58
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001064a07f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010648d343 dispatch_once_f + 565
10  ShareTales                          0x000000010275d6ef +[PFOfflineStore enableOfflineStore] + 252
11  ShareTales                          0x00000001026f4c0d _TFC10ShareTales11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 157
12  ShareTales                          0x00000001026f5d30 _TToFC10ShareTales11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb + 560
13  UIKit                               0x0000000104c5b475 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 234
14  UIKit                               0x0000000104c5bfbc -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2463
15  UIKit                               0x0000000104c5ed2c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
16  UIKit                               0x0000000104c5dbf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
17  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010c5602a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001047a953c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010479f285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010479f045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010479e486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
22  UIKit                               0x0000000104c5d669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
23  UIKit                               0x0000000104c60420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
24  ShareTales                          0x00000001026f8d8e top_level_code + 78
25  ShareTales                          0x00000001026f8dca main + 42
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001064d5145 start + 1
```

Any suggestion?

I tried also to move it after the Parse.setApplicationId

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    Parse.setApplicationId("appKey", clientKey:"clientKey")
```

and I have:

```
2014-12-11 20:38:28.118 ShareTales[67520:637437] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.
Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Objective-C, fyi

Comment: there is a bug reported to parse.com. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/751537214925590. I hope they solve it quickly

Comment: Yeah, that's my bug :-)

Comment: @TonyMkenu, this is not about the warning from calling a synchronous call on the main thread

Comment: follow this link:https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/806230492768791/ to be updated

Comment: Having the same issue in objective-c as well.

Out of interest, I tried enableLocalDatastore on a clean copy of ParseStarterProject 1.6.0 and it gave the same error. Definitely a bug.

Comment: @Dave yes, it is! The correct way it is to call `enableLocalDatastore ` after the  the Parse.setApplicationId; but there is another issues .. exact "about the warning from calling a synchronous call on the main thread"; he have something else in his code...

Answer (score 1):

I put the `[Parse enableLocalDatastore];` after the `[Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:];` and i got another errors. But this another errors was because you can't use Local Datastore and Cache Policy together. When i removed the Cache Policy's methods everything works fine. So, i don't know if this is a documentation mistake, but you have to put this code **after**.

Answer (score 0):

This error is sometimes caused by an incompatible linker flag in the iOS project templates.

To clear the error, go to your project's build settings in Xcode, and modify your "Other Linker Flags" setting:

1.) Remove "-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib"
2.) Add "-weak-lSystem"

With reference to: https://www.parse.com/questions/im-getting-an-exc_bad_access-when-trying-to-call-parse-setapplicationidclientkey-what-should-i-do

Comment: I tried but
1. I didn't have settet -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
2. I setted OTHER_LDFLAGS = -weak-lSystem
but the error still remains